# Pymongo subdocument update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, insert-update

Is this possible to do this short-form in python, I get the error,

```
>> collection.insert({u'name.first': u'John'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/someone/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 415, in insert
    self.uuid_subtype, client)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'name.first' must not contain '.'
```

Edited: Thanks to [shx2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2096752/shx2) for pointing me out, that *insert* should be *update*. And after some surfing on the web I found the answer to be,

```
>> collection.update({_id: <some_id_or_index>}, {$set: {<python_dict_object_to_be_updated>}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to *update* a (sub-document of an) existing document, and therefor you should use `update` and not `insert`.

`insert` is used for adding a *new* document to the collection.